# Intermittent 'access denied' 'accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript' error with applet in IE

Tags: java, security, applet

I have an applet which requires execute priveledges and which communicates with javascript. It is signed.

Recently, a few users (from 2000 total) have been experiencing problems when starting IE in the morning. The applet fails to start. Closing and reopening the browser usually solves the problem and the applet works.

I enabled applet tracing and got the following in the console: (sorry about the German but the key entries are in English)

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_23
Verwendung der JRE-Version 1.6.0_23-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Home-Verzeichnis des Benutzers = C:\Documents and Settings\user
.....
network: Cache-Eintrag gefunden [url: http://{sharepointportal}/_layouts/WebParts2010/ieLauncher.jar?version=2011120106, Version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache:  Read manifest for http://{sharepointportal}/_layouts/WebParts2010/ieLauncher.jar?version=2011120106: read=400 full=400
cache: Reading Signers from 1121 http://{sharepointportal}/_layouts/WebParts2010/ieLauncher.jar?version=2011120106 | C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\63\a69c47f-2eba4659.idx
security: Zertifizierungsstellen-Stammzertifikate wurden geladen aus C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
security: Bereitstellungszertifikate werden geladen aus C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Bereitstellungszertifikate wurden geladen aus C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Zertifikate werden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate werden aus Internet Explorer ROOT-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Internet Explorer ROOT-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate werden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikatskette mithilfe von CertPath-API prüfen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Keine Zeitstempelinformationen verfügbar
security: Zuständigkeitslistendatei gefunden
security: Beginn der Überprüfung auf vertrauenswürdige Erweiterung für dieses Zertifikat
security: Beginn des Vergleichs der Zuständigkeitsliste mit diesem Zertifikat
security: CRL-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: OCSP-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: Diese End Entity-Überprüfung mit OCSP ist deaktiviert.
security: Prüfen, ob Zertifikat im Zertifikatsspeicher Deployment denied ist
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
security: Zertifikate werden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate werden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikatskette mithilfe von CertPath-API prüfen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Keine Zeitstempelinformationen verfügbar
security: Zuständigkeitslistendatei gefunden
security: Beginn der Überprüfung auf vertrauenswürdige Erweiterung für dieses Zertifikat
security: Beginn des Vergleichs der Zuständigkeitsliste mit diesem Zertifikat
security: CRL-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: OCSP-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: Diese End Entity-Überprüfung mit OCSP ist deaktiviert.
security: Prüfen, ob Zertifikat im Zertifikatsspeicher Deployment denied ist
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
security: Zertifikate werden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate werden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikatskette mithilfe von CertPath-API prüfen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Keine Zeitstempelinformationen verfügbar
security: Zuständigkeitslistendatei gefunden
security: Beginn der Überprüfung auf vertrauenswürdige Erweiterung für dieses Zertifikat
security: Beginn des Vergleichs der Zuständigkeitsliste mit diesem Zertifikat
security: CRL-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: OCSP-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: Diese End Entity-Überprüfung mit OCSP ist deaktiviert.
security: Prüfen, ob Zertifikat im Zertifikatsspeicher Deployment denied ist
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Ausnahme: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
Ignored exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Ausnahme: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
Ignored exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.plugin.javascript)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but, as the problem is solved by restarting the browser, it can't be a certificate or priveledge problem. Right?

Does anyone have an idea what it might be or what else I could do to get more information?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The applet html

```
<APPLET ID='Launcher' 
    CODE='package.PortalLauncher.class' 
    ARCHIVE='ieLauncher.jar?version=2011120108'
    CODEBASE='../../../_layouts/WebParts2010/' 
    WIDTH='0' HEIGHT='0'>
    <div style='border: 1px red dotted; margin:10px;'>
        Dieser Webbrowser unterstützt das APPLET-Tag nicht!<br/>
        This browser does not support the APPLET tag!<br/>
    </div></APPLET>
```

**UPDATE2**

The applet is there to allow applications to be started directly from the browser. The link onclick event calls the applet with the application URL. The applet is allowed to start the executable. It is on the company portal and offers direct access to all the application which the current user is allowed to use.

Therefore it is a javascript to java link.

**UPDATE3**

I changed to tag from APPLET to OBJECT and added MAYSCRIPT, SCRIPTABLE etc (see suggestions) and started to test. I had the idea to add a second page to the Start Page list in my browser. A number of users start IBM Host on Demand automatically so I thought I would try it too. That's when the problems started for me. Every 2-3 times that I start the browser I get a problem with my applet. Looking at the trace, the difference which stikes me is that when the applet starts I get the following in the trace:

```
security: Prüfen, ob Zertifikat im Zertifikatsspeicher Deployment denied ist
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
security: Zertifikate werden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Bereitstellungssitzungs-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikate werden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
basic: Applet geladen
security: Zertifikate wurden aus Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher-Zertifikatspeicher geladen
security: Zertifikatskette mithilfe von CertPath-API prüfen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Zertifikatssammlung aus ZA-Stamm-Zertifikatsspeicher abrufen
security: Keine Zeitstempelinformationen verfügbar
security: Zuständigkeitslistendatei gefunden
security: Beginn der Überprüfung auf vertrauenswürdige Erweiterung für dieses Zertifikat
security: Beginn des Vergleichs der Zuständigkeitsliste mit diesem Zertifikat
security: CRL-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: OCSP-Unterstützung ist deaktiviert.
security: Diese End Entity-Überprüfung mit OCSP ist deaktiviert.
security: Prüfen, ob Zertifikat im Zertifikatsspeicher Deployment denied ist
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
basic: Applet geladen
```

When the applet loading fails then I get:

```
security: Zertifikat wird im permanenten Bereitstellungszertifikatspeicher gesucht
basic: Applet geladen
```

What this is saying is that a certificate is being looked for. When it works the success messages are displayed. When it fails then nothing further is traced. i.e. the certificate was probably not found. When I refresh the page, then it is successful.

Ideas?

Comment: What is the HTML used to launch the applet?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I just added an update

Comment: Add attribute 'MAYSCRIPT'. I do not understand how does it work  at all without this attribute.

Comment: BTW - which way is the applet/JS interaction?  If the JS is calling the applet, it might be the case that the JS is doing so before the (JRE &) applet is loaded and ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect AlexR has identified the cause of the problem, but some extra comments.

```
CODE='package.PortalLauncher.class'
```

Should be..

```
CODE='package.PortalLauncher'
```

And this..

```
WIDTH='0' HEIGHT='0'>
```

..is suspect ('hidden applet') and might cause the applet to be removed completely by over protective security plug-ins.

It is better to set a size of 20x20 and hide the applet by means of styles (CSS).

Make sure the HTML is validated.

---

I cannot explain the intermittent nature of the problem, but that is applets for you.

---

### Update

> It seems that when I set the style to 'display:none' then the applet is no longer loaded.

The W3C on [`display: none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)

> ..Please note that a display of 'none' does *not* create an invisible box; it creates *no box at all.*

*Emphasis* mine.  So it is not exactly surprising to me.  ;)

OTOH, what I actually meant was something along the lines of [`visibility: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility#Values)

> The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn)..

Put a shallow wide applet element at the bottom of the page and it will hardly be noticed.

Other things you might investigate to make an applet disappear:

- Make the applet a chameleon, accepting a color and painting the entire GUI with that color.  This will only work if the web page has a constant color BG (e.g. no BG images to hover over).
- Again using styles, shift the position of the applet element off the visible page using an absolute position of negative co-ordinates.  That is something I heard suggested a while ago.  I have not tried it.

Comment: Andrew, as far as I remember both `package.PortalLauncher.class` and `package.PortalLauncher` work fine. And I have never experienced problem using 0-size applet.

Comment: @AlexR  `package.PortalLauncher.class` is tolerated, but `package.PortalLauncher` is **correct.** (Quite an irritation, but most of the Sun/Oracle examples show the 'tolerated' form) *"And I have never experienced problem using 0-size applet."*  Fair enough, but what about the 50 visitors to the applet that the moment something did not work as they expected, surfed off somewhere else?  Are you *sure* you would hear from those clients or be otherwise informed of the applet failing?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the suggestion. It seems that when I set the style to 'display:none' then the applet is no longer loaded. This is not what I expected ;-)

Comment: @Andrew - I guess it doesn't make sense to render anything inside a display:none!. I didn't want to use hidden because, in my experience, it still reserves the space and leaves it empty. 1x1 size is fine with me in this case. Thanks

Comment: x marking as answer because there is a lot of useful stuff here. Unfortunately I still have the problem. I'm thinking now that it has something to do with other applets starting at the same time :-(

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure but I want to share with you my idea. Applet that calls javascript from outer page must be marked as 'MAYSCRIPT'.
I think that this exception will be thrown if applet is not marked as `MAYSCRIPT`. Try to check this: create static HTML page, add your applet to this page without `MAYSCRIPT` attribute. If you get the same exception, continue to the next steps.

My theory is that your HTML page creates tags dynamically including `applet` tag. So, probably sometimes the applet starts *before* the browser recognized that this applet can call javascript. This is the reason that refresh often solves the problem.

So, if all this correct try to modify the HTML page so that the applet will start only when browser has read all attributes of tag `applet`. Probably make dynamic code to be static or server generated.

I am sorry if my theory is totally wrong. I have not been implementing applets for years.

Comment: Quote from [Using OBJECT, EMBED and APPLET Tags in Java Plug-in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html) (from 1.4.2 - I could not be bothered hunting down a later ref.)  *"Please note that PARAM scriptable is not the same as the PARAM mayscript. mayscript provides support for communication from Java applets to JavaScript only, while scriptable allows communication from JavaScript to Java applets in Internet Explorer only."*  I don't know which the applet needs, but just thought I'd mention.

Comment: Good comment, Andrew. I have never used `scriptable` but called applets from javascript. But last time I wrote applet about 8 years ago, so java 1.4 was not even designed...

Comment: *"last time I wrote applet about 8 years ago"*  A few interesting things have happened to applets since then.  1.4 brought new applet methods, 1.5 offered new configuration params, 1.6 new params & access to JNLP API, draggable.. ;)

Comment: This just shows how old am I and that programmer cannot stop learning... :)

Comment: MAYSCRIPT worked inconsistently between browsers (bad). PlugIn2 (usual default from 6u10) should ignore it.